# Django ORM: slow SQL request using an update with a list of ids

Tags: django, database, performance, django-rest-framework

I have some database speed issues when doing an update with Django.

My request takes about 15s to be executed, updating ~1000 rows, which is quite slow

Here is a simplified version of my code

```
constant1 = sth
constant2 = sth

myList = Model.objects.filter(
    ...
)[:nb]

myListIds = []
for object in myList:

    ...
    myListIds.append(object.pk)

Model.objects.filter(
    pk__in=myListIds
).update(
    ...
    field1 = constant1,
    field2 = constant2,
    ...
)
```

I tried to look at the SQL request generated by Django, but it didn't teach me anything

What am I doing wrong here ?

My guess is that **pk__in** is the issue, but I can't find a workaround.
I need to use a list of ids in order to update because my queryset is sliced, and Django does not allow to update sliced queryset (*Cannot update a query once a slice has been taken.*)

Comment: Can you add the whole piece of related code into the post? So that I could find the main bottle neck.

Comment: `pk__in=myListIds` is super slow. You said that it's updating 1000 rows so I guess it's looking through the `myListIds` of 1000 elements 1000 times (1 million in total). You need to share more of your code and find workaround

Comment: @Metalgear thanks for your quick reply!

I don't think that I need to add more related code, as all the logic is already here.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you filter a queryset, insert ids in a list, and filter a new queryset with same ids. I think you can simply do this:

```
Model.objects.filter(
    ...
).update(
    ...
)
```

But if you need the for cycle and the slice, you can use [bulk_update()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_update) method

```
myList = Model.objects.filter(
    ...
)[:nb]

objs = []
for object in myList:
    ...
    objs.append(object)

Model.objects.bulk_update(objs)
```

or you can simply do:

```
myList = Model.objects.filter(
    ...
)[:nb]

for object in myList:
    ...
    object.field = constant1
    object.save()
```

Note: If you are searching to cut off execution time, [bulk_update()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_update) method accept as second param a list of fields, that can be useful for your pourpose.

Comment: Indeed, the for cycle and the slice are needed, because I need the object ids to perform some additional operations (not showed here for clarity pupose).

I know exactly what bulk_update does, but this is not suited for my usecase, because the updated values are identical (bulk_update is usefull when having differents values to update to the same model)

Comment: Ok, so try to use object.save() method in the cycle instead append to list? If you provide some additional infos about fields and values i can help you better.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if object.save() is a good idea, because it will not solve my initial issue, which is the speed.

Using object.save() in a for loop will generate N SQL requests

Comment: Sure, so you have to optimize the first query, set the fields through annotation fields (use nested case when if needed). But if you want more better answers you have to explain what do in the for cycle and why you have to do slice.